# SQL WHERE IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, where-clause

I'm writing in order to solve a particular SQL query.

Here's my situation: in which way is possible to perform a query that in a WHERE clause allow to identify (from another table) the equality of one field and the > of another?

Something like the IN clause:

```
select * 
from tableX
WHERE (tableX.field1, tableX.field2) IN (select tableY.field1, tableY.field2 from tableY)
```

In my case I need to identify all `filed1X` that are bigger than `field1Y` when `tableX.field2 = tableY.field2`.

Thanks.

Nico

Answer (score 1):

```
select tableX.field1 
from tableX innerjoin tableY on tableX.field2 = tableY.field2
where tableX.field1 > tabley.field1
```

Comment: A join is not necessarily a replacement for an `IN` query. What if there is more than one row in `tableY` that satisfies the join condition?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't think Nico was asking for a replacement for an IN query: he simply wants all instances of tableX.field1 that are greater than tabley.field2 where tablex.field two is equal to tabley.field two (hence the join).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tableX
WHERE exists (select 42 
              from tabley 
              where tableX.field2 = tableY.field2
                and tableX.field1X > tableY.field1Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
from tableX as t1, tableY as t2
where(t1.field1 = t2.field1) AND (t1.field2 > t2.field2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a join instead.

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM tableX x
JOIN tableY y on x.field2 = y.field2 AND x.field1 > y.field1
```